# Display Vertical text in react native like drawer

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I need to display text in vertical position. the text will be dynamic so it can be short or long. i've added the screenshot of what i want. can anybody share the code for this type of ui. thanks in advance.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAACB.jpg)

[see this, this is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJXLd.png)

```html
<View>
  <View style={{}}>
    <View
      style={{ marginTop: 30, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          fontSize: 20,
          alignSelf: "center",
          transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
          color: "white",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      >
        Short
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={{}}>
    <View
      style={{ marginTop: 30, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          fontSize: 20,
          alignSelf: "center",
          transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
          color: "white",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      >
        Long Text
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>;
```

Comment: hey you can use css property for text `transform: rotate<X|Y>(<Degs_Number>deg);`

Comment: Hi @kunalpanchal i did. but its not working.

Comment: could you please share your  code snippet here so that we can debug it ?

Comment: @kunalpanchal i've updated my question. you can see my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be in trouble if you try to apply the transformations one by one in all `<Text />`. Instead try to apply the transformations in a parent `<View />` which gives you more control of what is going on.

```js
const App = () => {
  const {width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
  const height = 80;

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        transform: [
          {rotate: '-90deg'}, // negative degrees is important for this calculations and have the text face the content as your desired result picture shows
          {translateX: -(screenHeight / 2)}, // rotation is being applied in the center so it's safe to move it half screen
          {translateX: height / 2}, // correct the x translation with half of our component height so it stays on screen
          {translateY: -screenWidth}, // rotation is being applied in the center so it's safe to move it full screen width
          {translateY: height / 2}, // correct the y translation with half of our component height so it stays on screen
        ],
        width: screenHeight, // swap screen width with screen height so the background covers the entirety of the screen
        height, // fixed height is important to apply corrections on transform you could also use a ref and get this size on runtime
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: 'white',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          margin: 10,
        }}>
        Short
      </Text>

      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: 'white',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          margin: 10,
        }}>
        Long Text
      </Text>

      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: 'white',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          margin: 10,
        }}>
        Very Long Long Text
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

You can check the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4upIg.png).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it need some changes for my requirement.